# How to change the colour of JComboBox's selected Item?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox, itemlistener

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JCombo extends JFrame
{
    JComboBox com1,com2;

    public JCombo()
    {


        com1 = new JComboBox();
        com2 = new JComboBox();

        com1.addItem("One");
        com1.addItem("two");
        com1.addItem("Three");

        com2.addItem("Clothe");
        com2.addItem("Food");
        com2.addItem("Drinks");
        com2.addItemListener(new Com2Action());

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(com1);
        this.add(com2);

        this.pack();
        this.validate();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class Com2Action implements ItemListener
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ae)
        {
            if(ae.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                com1.getSelectedItem();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            new JCombo();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Now in here, what I need to do is this.

1. Select an item from com2
2. Highlight the item which is in com1, at the moment you select an item from com2. That highlighting should be there permanently (which means, the highlight should not go away when the user clicks on the com1 again)

EX:  you select 'Food' from com2. At that time, 'One' is displayed in com1. So, highlight it

How can I make this done? Please help!

Comment: `JComboBox` uses a `SingleSelectionModel` so only one selection can be done, at a time. On `JList` this can be done.

Comment: selected Item in dropdown list??, when popup is expanded??

Comment: I think you didn't get what I am saying. I want to highlight the item in com1, when an action in com2 performed. For an example, you select 'Food' from com2. At that time, 'One' is displayed in com1. So, highlight it

Comment: Your title gives room for bad understanding your problem...

Comment: @Sepala well, then I missing answer/details to my second part

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways

- change keys value in `UIManager`
- override `isSelected` in `DefaultListCellRenderer`

for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboRendererTest {

    public ComboRendererTest() {
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(1));
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(2.25));
        comboBox.addItem(new Double(3.5));
        comboBox.setRenderer(new TwoDecimalRenderer(comboBox.getRenderer()));
        comboBox.setEditable(true);

        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox1.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(1));
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(2.25));
        comboBox1.addItem(new Double(3.5));
        comboBox1.setRenderer(new TwoDecimalRenderer(comboBox.getRenderer()));
        comboBox1.setEditable(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(comboBox1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ComboRendererTest comboRendererTest = new ComboRendererTest();
            }
        });
    }
}

class TwoDecimalRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private ListCellRenderer defaultRenderer;

    public TwoDecimalRenderer(ListCellRenderer defaultRenderer) {
        this.defaultRenderer = defaultRenderer;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            if (isSelected) {
                c.setBackground(Color.blue);
            } else {
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.red);
            c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                    list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set custom renderer using JComboBox.setRenderer(ListCellRenderer aRenderer)